# How to do play next music and pause current music in dynamic content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Hi is there a way in javascript to play next song and pause current playing song since this is dynamic and they have the same id and onClick value. How can we handle dynamic content in javascript?

[image]

> index.ejs

```
<% music.forEach(function(muzic){ %>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="featured-image" src="/uploads/featured-img/<%= muzic.featured_img %>" alt="">
        <div class="card-img-overlay" id="toggleIcon">
            <a onClick="togglePlay()" class="select-play">
                <img class="select-play-btn" src="/img/select-play.png" id="play-pause" width="80">
                <audio id="myAudio" src="/uploads/audio-file/<%= muzic.audio %>"></audio>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% }); %>
```

> script

```
<script>
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
    isPlaying ? myAudio.pause() : myAudio.play();

    var img = document.getElementById('play-pause').src;
    if (img.indexOf('select-play.png')!=-1) {
        document.getElementById('play-pause').src  = '/img/pause-outline.png';
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById('play-pause').src = '/img/select-play.png';
    }

    var element = document.getElementById("toggleIcon");
    element.classList.toggle("pause-style");
};

myAudio.onplaying = function() {
    isPlaying = true;
};
myAudio.onpause = function() {
    isPlaying = false;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass values inside the `togglePlay(1)` and add a if else condition statement inside code.

```
function togglePlay(n){
    if(n==1){
       //do this
           }
   else   {
       //do that
          }
}
```

in index.ejs pass one more parameter `index` through forEach funcion like

```
<% music.forEach(function(muzic,index){ %>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="featured-image" src="/uploads/featured-img/<%= muzic.featured_img %>" alt="">
        <div class="card-img-overlay" id="toggleIcon">
            <a onClick="togglePlay(<%= index %>)" class="select-play">
                <img class="select-play-btn" src="/img/select-play.png" id="play-pause" width="80">
                <audio id="myAudio" src="/uploads/audio-file/<%= muzic.audio %>"></audio>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% }); %>
```

use the id as a paramter to identify the audio and do the algorith

Comment: But it is dynamic I cant pud values inside each togglePlay()

Comment: i will recommend you to use, one more object in 'music' as 'playing' , make the value as boolean and pass it through the togglePlay(<%= muzic.playing %>).

Comment: hi got an idea, how about I will add the table id in the togglePlay() parameter like onClick="togglePlay(<%= muzic.id %>)" but it is error. is there a way to put the table  id in a parameter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319106/how-can-we-do-autoplay-next-audio-in-dynamic-element

Answer (score 1):

you need to get all musics in array of musics first
and then start control all of them

example :

```
   // array who has all musics as playlist
    var Musics = [] ;
    // for target current played music in playlist Musics 
    var currentMusicPlayed = 0;
    
    // 3 paths of music
    let arrayOfPaths = ["./Music1.mp3" , "./Music2.mp3" , "./Music3.mp3"];
    
    // loop for making audio objects and push all of them in Musics Playlist array
    for(let i = 0 ; i < arrayOfPaths.length ; i += 1){
    
        let music = new Audio();
            music.src = arrayOfPaths[i];
    
        Musics.push(music);
    
    }
    
    // music player
    function MusicListPlayer(){
        // play current music who has 
        Musics[currentMusicPlayed].play();
    
        // and stop any music
        for(let i = 0 ; i < Musics.length ; i += 1){
            if(i != currentMusicPlayed){
                Musics[currentMusicPlayed].pause();
            }
        }
    
        // if current music index >= must be start from 0 again
        if(currentMusicPlayed >= i ) currentMusicPlayed = 0;
        // else increment for next click 
        else currentMusicPlayed += 1;
    }
    
    // just a random element for example
    const buttonGetNextMusic = document.querySelector("any");
    
    // here in click MusicListPlayer must be called and make next music in Array work
    buttonGetNextMusic.addEventListener("click" , MusicListPlayer);
```

i hope this example help you to understand the idea

Comment: let arrayOfPaths = ["./Music1.mp3" , "./Music2.mp3" , "./Music3.mp3"];
how can that be done?
how can i fetch my audio list from database and assign a varriable like that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319106/how-can-we-do-autoplay-next-audio-in-dynamic-element