# How can we do autoplay next audio in dynamic element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

How can we do auto-play next audio and auto-pause current if audio is played?
How can we do an incremental function to access my next audio which is in array.

```
<% music.forEach(function(muzic){ %>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="play-wrap card">
        <img class="featured-image" src="/uploads/featured-img/<%= muzic.featured_img %>" alt="<%= muzic.title %> - <%= muzic.band_name%>">
        <div class="card-img-overlay" id="toggleIcon">
            <a class="select-play">
                <img class="select-play-btn" src="/img/select-play.png" id="play-pause" width="80">
                <audio id="myAudio" class="myMusic" src="/uploads/audio-file/<%= muzic.audio %>"></audio>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% }); %>

<script>
$(".select-play").click(function() {
    var audio = $(this).closest('.play-wrap').find('.myMusic')[0];
    
    audio.play();

    audio.onended = function() {
        for(var i = 0, len = audio.length; i < len; i++){
            audio[i].play();
        };
    };
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: `audio.onended = function() {
   //Do whatever you want  
};`

Comment: else if (audio.onended) is this okay?

Comment: but how can i access my audio[]?

Comment: i cant just do audio.src

Comment: @SourabhSomani hi I updated my question and script